# D3.js force layout : show root path of any node

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using force layout of d3.js and I need to show the path to the root in graph. Ex- On click of "Task 10" node it should show the path (Task 10->Task 6-> Task 4-> Task 1). Root will be recognize as same source and target but this info I am passing in data only. My data contain "RootPath" having path info for the node like for "Task 10" RootPath is ["Task 6","Task 4","Task 1"] .

My complete code for the graph can be seen here http://plnkr.co/edit/EvpNC6B5DBWczNXKiL82?p=preview.

I am writing below method so that on click to the particular node it will show the root path. But currently it only show for 1 node. I don't know how to iterate for all other lists of node.

```
  function rootPath(d){
    var curNodeDetail = d.details.RootPath;
    var source=[],target=[],i=0,j=0;
    source[i] = d.name;
    target[i] = curNodeDetail[i];
    links.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            if(source[i] === o.source.name && target[i] === o.target.name){
                source[i+1] = curNodeDetail[i];
                target[i+1] = curNodeDetail[i+1];
                i++;
                return  1;      
            }
            else    
                return 0.1;     
        })
        .attr("marker-end", function(o){
                if(source[j] === o.source.name && target[j] === o.target.name){
                        j++;
                        return "url(#arrowhead)";
                }
                else
                    return "url(#arrowhead2)";
        });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn d.details.rootpath into a d3.set and add the current node, then interrogate each link to see if both ends are part of the set.

This works for your links, but you'll have to do likewise for the nodes -->

```
var curNodeDetail = d.details.RootPath;
var rootMap = d3.set (curNodeDetail);
rootMap.add(d.name);
links.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
        return (rootMap.has(o.source.name) && rootMap.has (o.target.name)) ? 1 : 0.1;
    })
    .attr("marker-end", function(o){
            return (rootMap.has(o.source.name) && rootMap.has (o.target.name)) ? "url(#arrowhead)" : "url(#arrowhead2)";
    });
```

}

Comment: I think map (key-value pair) will be useful for interrogate each link. Here in map I will insert source as key and target as value. Let take an ex for Task 10 i will insert ("Task 10","Task 6"),("Task 6","Task 4"),("Task 4","Task 1") and each link it will be check in map. I don't how to implement this using d3.map().. I and search that.

Comment: Thanks mgraham, I have implemented it :)

Answer (score 0):

Below function can be useful :-

```
function rootPath(d){
    var curNodeDetail = d.details.RootPath;
    var rootMap = rootPathItinerary(d.name,curNodeDetail);
    links.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
            return (rootMap.has(o.source.name) && (rootMap.get(o.source.name) === o.target.name)) ? 1 : 0.1;
    })
    .attr("marker-end", function(o){
            return (rootMap.has(o.source.name) && (rootMap.get(o.source.name) === o.target.name)) ? "url(#arrowhead)" : "url(#arrowhead2)";
    });
}

function rootPathItinerary(node,rootPathDet){
    var i=0;
    var map = d3.map();
    map.set(node,rootPathDet[i]);//10,6
    while(i+1 <rootPathDet.length){ //6,4,1
            map.set(rootPathDet[i],rootPathDet[i+1]) ; //6,4 ; 4,1
            i++;
    }
    return map;
}
```